# How to properly measure download speed?

Tags: sockets, udp

I have a device connected through Gigabit Ethernet to my PC. They're in the same network (device and PC) and I use UDP to download data from the device to the PC.

The way I'm measuring speed is starting a timer, starting the download and stopping the timer after the download is completed. Then divide number of bytes by elapsed time. I repeat the same thing several time and then obtain the average speed.

The thing is, speed changes as I change the size of the downloaded data. So if I download 200 KB I get a different speed than if I donwload 500 MB. Also, speed when downloading 500 MB is much higher than when downloading 200 KB (that is, it takes longer to download 200 KB than 500 MB).

Am I doing this right? Why do I get different measures depending on the size (I expected to get similar results)? Would you do it differently?